# Simple persistent message queue in C# for a single process

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, persistent-storage

I'm doing a simple Messaging system for a Windows Mobile in C#. The application consists in sending and receiving simple text messages using a Web service communication. The messages queue should be persistent, avoiding data lost if the connection with the web service fail or the application crash.

I know about MSMQ, RabbitMQ, DotNetMQ, but they should be installed in the device and this are really simple devices, I don't want to install any other tool in each of the mobiles just for this simple task.

I already implemented the function to write an XML serialized queue with the messages into a file and I read and write all the time from this file.

I'd appreciate any better idea to solve this problem.
Thanks

Comment: Windows Mobile has been obsolete for years. Do you mean Windows Phone or Windows 10 Mobile? If so, why not just use push notifications?

Comment: Windows Mobile 6.5! and yes they are old! they are used for a very few tasks, like this messaging application.

Comment: Though this is an old question it is gaining views still. Would the OP care to select an answer or provide more comments?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there is a better idea is to use [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/).
I hope this will help you.

Comment: It might be worth explaining your answer in the future. SQLite IS a good way to provide persistence for a small queue system, but you failed to explain why. As you can tell, this question is still gaining views through search engines, prompting my reply.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what's available for Windows Mobile but you can try using basic queue (normal or concurrent, depends on your app) accompanied by two files. Write everything that is enqueued to one "Enqueue log" file and write everything that is dequeued  to another "Dequeue log" file.
This two files can always give you enough information to restore your queue, and you don't need to fully rewrite/fully serialize your queue. It needs to be implemented by hand though.

About dequeue:
for example, lets say I have a queue with 3 messages: "one", "two", "three". Now I want to send the next (also the first) message "one". I append the line "one - starting removal from queue" to my "dequeue log", then I dequeue "one" from my queue object and send it where I want it to be sent to. When it is sent, I append " - finished removal from queue" to my "dequeue log". Now I have a line "one - starting removal from queue - finished removal from queue" in my log file.

It doesn't matter when do I crash, I'll always will be able to restore the state of queue object (at least for now I fail to see any logic mistakes in this process). So imho it's not tricky but still... some code should be coded. And it would be a few pages of code.

Comment: Also this two files should be cleaned from time to time in some "crash persistent" way. For example, when "Dequeue log" becomes longer than 1000 messages, create new "Dequeue log 2" and then delete the old one. Same goes for "Enqueue log" with respect to messages need to be removed before they can be deleted.

Comment: thank you for the answer, actually I'm doing something similar to your idea. As my messages are retrieved as XML by the SOAP Web Service, I'm just appending the messages in a file, in that way the enqueue and getTheFirstElement is easy, the tricky part is the dequeue.

Comment: @MariaSilvia edited my answer just in case with my thoughts on dequeue process. As far as I remember it's how I did it (I had to implement custom persistent .Net MQ for back-end system).

Answer (score 0):

[MSMQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms834460.aspx) does not need to be installed is supported natively on Windows Mobile 6.5 devices. BTW: there are still many vendors in industrial area providing WM65 based devices, so this is not yet outdated.

The Windows Mobile (CE) based MSMQ is persistent and simple to use. It is normally used for interprocess-communication on the device or for client server communication (which requires MSMQ installed on the 'server').

So, the main thread creates a MSMQ, one thread in your process fills the MSMQ and another can 'peek' and, after successful transmission, 'dequeue' messages from the same MSMQ. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172497%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for a simple example.

Comment: I have tried to create the  message queue in the device without installing it and it gave me an Exception: "Message Queuing has not been installed on this computer."

Comment: Maybe you tried the wrong msmq implementation? See sample code at https://github.com/hjgode/rdmInject/blob/master/RDM_msg_queue/msgqueue.cs. This is code to process msgs posted by the rdm_inject dll code. BTW: there are already running many MSMQ implementations on WM startup to let you watch PowerNotifications or PlugNPlay device changes etc. I have used various of these in my projects hosted on github (ie https://github.com/hjgode/logging_ce/blob/master/PowerMsgLog/PowerMsgQueue.cpp and thers in this logging_ce folder)